# Java: thin jar with all dependencies

Tags: java, jar, dependencies, executable-jar

Assuming I have the following Java classes:

**Foo.java:**

```
package my.small.question;
import my.common.stuff.Bar;
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
        bar.init();
    }
}
```

**Bar.java:**

```
package my.common.stuff;
import my.algorithms.SpecialSauce;
public class Bar {

    private SpecialSauce yum;

    public Bar() {
        this.yum = new SpecialSauce(888) ;
        yum.bake();
    }
}
```

If I want to create one runnable jar from `Foo.class` I need to have the depended packages in it - `Bar.class` & `SpecialSauce.class` BUT common package have many other classes (`Baz.class`, `Baq.class` etc...) that are not used in any flow form `Foo.class` and also `my.algorithms` package has many other unneeded algorithms - you got the idea...

**My Question**

How automatically (tool?) can I make a thin jar from **Foo.java** that will contain only the must-have classes and their dependencies (recursively) and nothing else?

Comment: There may be jars/classes that are needed only at compile time - for example jax-rs definitions, and also there may be jars that are needed only at run time - say, when you try to locate them via JNDI lookup/OSGI. 
See similar questions: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42796/a-tool-to-remove-unneeded-classes-from-jar-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099121/remove-unused-jars-from-project

Comment: You can use Maven- you split the code into different projects; each project is built into an artifact (a jar with an artifact-id and version); and every project can depend on any other project. Maven manages the dependencies for you; you can collect all of the project's dependencies (and that gives the minimum set of jars needed for the project)